# Give an example of a convergent series .

Tags: sequences-and-series

Give an example of a convergent series ∑an  such that  the seties ∑a3n   is divergent.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{3n}?$$

Comment: Or do you mean $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n\quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n^3\,?$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $a_{3n}=\frac1{2n}$, $a_{3n+1}=\frac{-1}{2n+1}$, and $a_{3n+2}=0$.

Then,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\frac12\ln(2)-\frac12$$

But,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{3n}=\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

This waltz on the harmonic series seems to meet the requirements:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ldots\\
a_{3n} &=& 1/n \\
a_{3n+1} &=& -1/(2n+1) \\
a_{3n+2} &=& -1/(2n+2) \\
\ldots
\end{eqnarray*}